# Design issues with an integrating ADC

Tags: adc, integrator

I have designed a dual slope integrating ADC on Multisim, but I am having some practical limitations.

To switch between the input voltage and the reference voltage, I am using the following switching circuit:

IO_1 can be given a digital signal to switch between the two voltages. The first voltage is from IO_2, and the other is the 0.4 V input at the second transistor.

[image]

Now, to combine the outputs IO_3 and IO_4, I am using a summing amplifier, but the summing amplifier needs to be powered above the range of the input, otherwise the output from the summer will saturate. This is severely restricting my range.

How can I overcome this problem. Is my switching circuit inefficient?

Comment: None of those is the ADC chip. But yes, DMMs use slope integration.

Comment: I think the ADC chip might be on the other side.

Comment: It's definitely on the other side. Underneath the LCD.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm assuming you think so because of the copper pour and congregation of traces? Just curious

Comment: @crasic: It's only a surprise in the first 3 DMMs you look inside. After that it's *always* under the LCD.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit the question and rather directly ask the design query I have.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I have edited the question now.

Comment: I do not have enough to answer, but you need to have a secondary stage to condition your signal for your input stage. If you need a quick solution on a breadboard you should buffer your inputs with an opamp into a voltage divider.

Comment: @crasic: so basically you are saying that I should use the voltage divider to minimize my input and bring it under the V_cc of my op amp? I think this would work because the divider preserves the linearity of the input.

Comment: @Sidd conceptually yes, this is basically why oscilloscopes and dmm's have knobs. There are more precise ways to couple your input to handle more exact requirements. But essentially you want your ADC to read a voltage that is always in the same range and use analog ciruits to condition your input to that range (perhaps in logarithmic scale steps). Your input stage is determined by the nature of your signal.